# Returning a limited type in Ada

Tags: ada

I am trying to return a limited type via a constructor function. I understand that because it is a limited type, I cannot copy the type but I am not sure of the best way to do it. I have it working using an extended return statement but I have been told that I should be able to return a limited type without it.

thing_protected.ads:

```
package Thing_Protected is

   type Thing is protected interface;
   procedure Verb_It (Object : in out Thing; Key : String) is abstract;

   function Create return Thing'Class;

private

   protected type Thing_Impl is new Thing with
      overriding procedure Verb_It (Key : String);
   private
      Data : Integer;
   end Thing_Impl;

end Thing_Protected;
```

thing_protected.adb:

```
package body Thing_Protected is

   function Create return Thing'Class is
   begin

        -- Not sure how to make this work:
        -- return Thing_Impl'(Data=><>, others=><>);
        --  thing_protected.adb:6:35: expected type "Thing_Impl" defined at thing_protected.ads:10
        --  thing_protected.adb:6:35: found a composite type

        -- extended return:
        --  return X : Thing_Impl do
        --      null;
        --  end return;

        -- shortened version:
        return X : Thing_Impl;
   end;

  protected body Thing_Impl  is
      overriding procedure Verb_It (Key : String) is
      begin
        null;
      end;
   end Thing_Impl;

end Thing_Protected;
```

main.adb:

```
with Thing_Protected;

procedure Main is
   Thing_Instance : Thing_Protected.Thing'Class := Thing_Protected.Create;
begin
    null;
end;
```

Comment: There's no aggregate syntax (`return Thing_Impl'(...)`) for protected or task types.  So I think you have to use extended return.  (By the way, the `overriding` on the body of `Verb_It` is illegal even if your compiler incorrectly accepts it.)

Comment: See also [*4.5 Limited types and return statements*](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rat/html/Rat-4-5.html) for related examples.

Comment: ajb: I think `overriding` is perfectly legal here. According to the [ARM](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-9-4.html#S0196), a `protected_operation_declaration` can be a `subprogram_declaration`, which can have the `overriding` indicator.

Comment: @flyx see [AC-00213](http://www.ada-auth.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/acs/ac-00213.txt?rev=1.1).

Comment: I originally claimed that this was possible without extended return, but as ajb pointed out, aggregates cannot be used here (I wasn't aware of that), so an extended return is actually the right solution.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, so you want to initialize Data? You could use generics/packages to do that... it's a little long and perhaps a little convoluted.

```
package Thing_Protected is

type Thing is protected interface;

procedure Verb_It (Object : in out Thing; Key : String) is abstract;

function Create return Thing'Class;

private

generic
    Default : in Integer;
package Implementation is
    protected type Thing_Impl is new Thing with
    procedure Verb_It (Key : String);
    private
    Data : Integer:= Default;
    end Thing_Impl;

    Function Create return Thing'Class;
end Implementation;

end Thing_Protected;

package body Thing_Protected is

package body Implementation is
    protected body Thing_Impl  is
    overriding procedure Verb_It (Key : String) is
    begin
        null;
    end;
    end Thing_Impl;

    function  Create return Thing'class is
    begin
    return Result : Thing_Impl do
        null;
    end return;
    end Create;
end Implementation;


function K( Data_Val : Integer := 10 ) return Thing'Class is
    Package I is new Implementation( Default => Data_Val );
begin
    return X : Thing'Class := I.Create do
    null;
    end return;
end K;


function Create return Thing'Class is ( K );

end Thing_Protected;
```